# Find the function name in a java file, which has specific string

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a requirement to find out the function names in java files, which has a specific string.

Example:

**Sample.java**

```
public void name()
{
 statement 1 - first line
 statement 2 - hello world!
 statement 3 - new line 
}
```

I have to search all the functions in file having "hello word" string in anywhere in the function.

Someone please help me in get me the way to do that in Shell script?

Comment: are the blocks separated by newlines? then you could simply do:  `awk -v RS= '/hello world/' Sample.java`

Comment: Thanks Sundeep for the command. It can fetch the line "statement 2 - hello world!", but I need to get function "name()" as output if the function has "Hello World".